# Combining SQL string alias into comma delimited string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services, concatenation

I am working on this stored proc which check to see which BIT fields are true and depending on it assigns a text to it using alias name. I want to be able to combine these alias values (string) and have it comma delimited to I can display it on my SSRS report. 
Below is part of my stored proc.

```
 ,CASE
  WHEN sr.[ReservationAlreadySentAttached] = 1 THEN 'Reservation Already Sent'
  END                           AS ReservationAttached

  ,CASE
  WHEN sr.[HPOfficeAttached] = 1 THEN 'H&P Office'
  END                           AS HPOfficeAttached

  WHEN sr.[NotesAttached] = 1 THEN 'Notes'
  END                           AS NotesAttached

  ,CASE
  WHEN sr.[OpPermitAttached] = 1 THEN 'Op Permit'
  END                           AS OpPermitAttached

  ,CASE
  WHEN sr.[TestResultsAttached] = 1 THEN 'Test Results'
  END                           AS TestResultsAttached

  ,CASE
  WHEN sr.[ConsultationReportsAttached] = 1 THEN 'Consultation Reports'
  END                           AS ConsultationReportsAttached

  ,CASE
  WHEN sr.[OtherAttached] = 1 THEN 'Other'
  END                           AS OtherAttached
```

so lets say in case where only NotesAttached and ReservationAlreadySentAttached were only true ones then I want the end result to come out as Notes, Reservation Already Sent. 
How do i concatenate these aliases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to build your string and then just remove the leading comma with STUFF()

**Example (abbreviated)**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ReservationAlreadySentAttached bit,HPOfficeAttached bit,NotesAttached bit)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,0,1)

Select NewValue = stuff(
                   case when ReservationAlreadySentAttached = 1 then ', Reservation Already Sent' else '' end
                  +case when HPOfficeAttached               = 1 then ', H&P Office'               else '' end
                  +case when NotesAttached                  = 1 then ', Notes'                    else '' end
                  ,1,2,'')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
NewValue
Reservation Already Sent, Notes
```

> **EDIT - Just the Expression**

```
 NewValue = stuff(
                   case when sr.[ReservationAlreadySentAttached] = 1 then ', Reservation Already Sent' else '' end
                  +case when sr.[HPOfficeAttached]               = 1 then ', H&P Office'               else '' end
                  +case when sr.[NotesAttached]                  = 1 then ', Notes'                    else '' end
                  ,1,2,'')
```

Comment: I am getting stuck at your answer @John Cappelletti . why do i need to declare a table ?i just wanted a string concatenated with my aliases

Comment: @HereToLearn_ The (at)YourTable is just a table variable used for demonstration / illustration.  Delete everything above the SELECT (first 3 lines) and change (at)YourTable to your table name

Comment: @HereToLearn_ Updated answer with "Just the Expression"

Comment: ok cool. thanks for quick response! What does 1,2 signify ? I was going to add 4 more  cases inside the stuff parenthesis. Do i need to update anything else too ?

Comment: @HereToLearn_ Stuff() will replace characters starting with position 1 for 2 spaces with ''... thus eliminating the leading ,{space}

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE
  WHEN sr.[ReservationAlreadySentAttached] = 1 THEN ', Reservation Already Sent' ELSE ''
  END  
+ CASE
  WHEN sr.[HPOfficeAttached] = 1 THEN ', H&P Office' ELSE ''
  END                        
+ CASE etc...
```

And wrap this in some function to remove the first comma + space.

Comment: Without the ELSE, you run the risk of concatenating NULL's

Comment: Question @TabAlleman . Where do I define the variable string which is going to have the final concatenated list of string?

Comment: If you want to populate a variable then you would put it before the column definition like `@MyVariable=STUFF(CASE WHEN...`

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest solution...

```
RIGHT((CASE 
        WHEN sr.[ReservationAlreadySentAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Reservation Already Sent'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[HPOfficeAttached] = 1
            THEN ',H&P Office'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[NotesAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Notes'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[OpPermitAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Op Permit'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[TestResultsAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Test Results'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[ConsultationReportsAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Consultation Reports'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[OtherAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Other'
        END)
,LEN(CASE 
        WHEN sr.[ReservationAlreadySentAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Reservation Already Sent'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[HPOfficeAttached] = 1
            THEN ',H&P Office'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[NotesAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Notes'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[OpPermitAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Op Permit'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[TestResultsAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Test Results'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[ConsultationReportsAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Consultation Reports'
        END + CASE 
        WHEN sr.[OtherAttached] = 1
            THEN ',Other'
        END) - 1 )
```

Edit: You may have to take into consideration when NONE of them are 1 so you don't get `Invalid length parameter passed to the right function.`